# NGINX - Set root to sub directory

Tags: nginx

I use [Trellis](https://roots.io/trellis/) from the [Roots.io](https://roots.io/) WordPress framework stack. It sets up a LEMP environment for me.

The nginx root path is set to: `root /srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web;`

- Inside the `/web` directory is a directory called `/static`.

Long story short. I want all traffic to be sent to the `/srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static` directory. So it acts like /static is the root and loads the website from there.

- I do not mean like this: https://www.example.co.uk/static
- Instead, https://www.example.co.uk/ should load from `/srv/www/example.co.uk/current/web/static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Have a read of the Nginx includes docs.
https://roots.io/docs/trellis/master/nginx-includes/#child-templates

Create the following directory and file (per site) inside of Trellis.
`/trellis/nginx-includes/mysite.co.uk.conf.child`

```
{% extends 'roles/wordpress-setup/templates/wordpress-site.conf.j2' %}

{% block change_nginx_root_path %}

# Change NGINX root path
root /srv/www/mysite.co.uk/current/web/static;

{% endblock -%}
```

Update the `mysite.co.uk`.